# An analytic function $f$ bounded on the right half plane and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on the imaginary axis

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $f$ is an analytic function that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on the imaginary axis and that $f$ is bounded in the right half plane. Prove that in fact $|f(z)|\leq 1$ in the right half plane. Hint: Consider the function $f_{\epsilon}(z)=f(z) e^{-\epsilon \sqrt{z}\,\,\,}$ for small positive $\epsilon$.

Even though there is a hint I couldn't figure out how to approach to this question. If the function is conformal the statement is true but what we have otherwise? any help would be great.

Comment: What is the problem in dealing with $f$ directly? And what does $f_\epsilon$ give us over $f$ that makes the problem disappear?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: As $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$  $|f_{\epsilon}| \rightarrow |f|$ but how we interpreate that?

Comment: Consider a fixed $\epsilon > 0$. What do you know about $f_\epsilon$?

Comment: @Daniel Fisher: $f_{\epsilon}$ has the same hypothesis as $f$.

Comment: Yes, but we have a little more. What do you now about $z \mapsto e^{-\epsilon \sqrt{z}}$?

Comment: @Daniel Fisher: It is analytic in a domain of a branch of log,  but its absolute value can be smaller than $1$ and also bigger than $1$ on the right half plane, so multiplying by it doesnt bring something to us?

Comment: We're looking only at the right half-plane (and, although it has not been explicitly stated, we of course look at the branch of the square root [defined on the right half-plane!] with $\sqrt{1} = 1$).

Comment: @Daniel Fisher: So the absolute value of $e^{- \epsilon \sqrt {z} }\,\,\,$   is increasing to $1$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ so the result came.

Comment: _How_ does that take us to the desired result?

Comment: @Daniel Fisher: I thought multiplying by $e^{-\epsilon \sqrt{z}}\,\,$ make the absolute value of $f$ is strictly bigger so if $f$ is bounded by $M$ on the right half plane then $M$ has to be $1$, but now I think that my conclusion is not true. Could you help please because I lost. Thank yo very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We take the branch of $\sqrt{z}$ with $\sqrt{1} = 1$ on the right half-plane. Then for $z = re^{i\varphi}$ in the right half plane - with $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \varphi < \frac{\pi}{2}$ - we have $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}\cdot e^{i\varphi/2}$, so $\operatorname{Re} \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{\lvert z\rvert}\cos \frac{\varphi}{2} \geqslant \sqrt{\lvert z\rvert}\cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \sqrt{\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{2}}$.

Thus, if we know $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant M$ in the right half-plane, we have

$$\lvert f_\epsilon(z)\rvert \leqslant M e^{-\epsilon\sqrt{\lvert z\rvert/2}} \leqslant 1\tag{$\ast$}$$

for $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 2\bigl(\frac{\log M}{\epsilon}\bigr)^2$. But the maximum modulus principle then tells us that also

$$\lvert f_\epsilon(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$$

in the half-disk $\Bigl\{ z : \operatorname{Re} z > 0, \lvert z\rvert < 2\bigl(\frac{\log M}{\epsilon}\bigr)^2\Bigr\}$, since we know $\lvert f_\epsilon(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ on the boundary of that half-disk. On the semicircle $\lvert z\rvert = 2\bigl(\frac{\log M}{\epsilon}\bigr)^2$, that follows from $(\ast)$, and on the part of the imaginary axis, it follows from the assumption that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ there and the fact that $\lvert e^{-\epsilon\sqrt{z}}\rvert \leqslant 1$ on the closed right half-plane.

So we have $\lvert f_\epsilon(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ on the whole right half-plane for every $\epsilon > 0$. But then

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert = \lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} \lvert f_\epsilon(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$$

for every $z$ in the right half-plane.